# How to make custom element types restorable?

Tags: craft3, modules, elementaction, soft-deletes

In Craft CMS 3, custom element types support soft-deletion out of the box.

But once soft-deleted, there is now way to restore elements that are now listed in the **Trashed** status, the only available action is **Delete permanently**.

[image]

How can you make custom elements restorable?

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 solutions:

- Implement your own `Restore` action, or
- Be lazy and reuse `\craft\elements\actions`

I won't cover implementing you own action, let's be lazy!

#### Declare the action

To do this, you need to override the `defineActions()` method of your element's class:

```
protected static function defineActions(string $source = null): array
{
    $actions = parent::defineActions($source);

    // Restore
    $actions[] = Craft::$app->getElements()->createAction([
        'type' => \craft\elements\actions\Restoreclass,
        'successMessage' => Craft::t('your-module', 'Elements restored.'),
        'partialSuccessMessage' => Craft::t('your-module', 'Some elements restored.'),
        'failMessage' => Craft::t('your-module', 'Elements not restored.'),
    ]);

    return $actions;
}
```

Craft will automatically hide the restore action when the selected status is not **Trashed** ([here's how](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/20a3c7990e2ff9b7be87bc939b7a46de6c3b579a/src/controllers/ElementIndexesController.php#L583-L591)).

The **Restore** action is now shown when viewing the **Trashed** elements.
[image]

But using it will result in a 500 error 
Let's fix that.

#### Add an `essentials` scenario to your element

`craft\elements\actions`, tries to validate the elements being restored using the `essentials` scenario. If your element doesn't have such scenario, restoration will fail.

To add a new scenario, you need to override your element's `scenarios()` method:

```
public function scenarios()
{
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios[self::SCENARIO_ESSENTIALS] = [ 
        // list here the name of attributes to validate when restoring
    ];

    return $scenarios;
}
```

You should now be able to restore element